# Dashboard in WSO2 Micro Integrator 7.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

*Hello Everyone,*

I took the latest release code of micro integrator from GitHub and build micro integrator zip from that.
I used the zip file and was able to deploy CAR files on that without any issue.
But I am not able to find any script to start dashboard. Any idea how can i start dashboard using zip that i build from GitHub code?
PS: I am not using binary to install micro integrator. With binary, micro-dashboard comes by default.

Thanks,
Vipin

Answer (score 0):

Micro Integrator repo does not contain the dashboard distribution. It is available at https://github.com/wso2/product-mi-tooling. If you build the monitoring dashboard folder you can get the dashboard distribution.